# Difference of elements in object where key not always available

Tags: php, arrays, object, iteration

I have an array ($data['messages']) of objects, and i want to find mileage difference, so on below example it is 5200-5000 = 200 km.

The thing is that the key now always exists.
What is the fastest or shortest way, without errors that key do not exist.

```
Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [speed] => 5
    )
[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [speed] => 6
        [mileage] => 5000
    )
[2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [speed] => 9
    )
[4] => stdClass Object
    (
        [speed] => 2
        [mileage] => 5200
    ) 
[5] => stdClass Object
    (
        [speed] => 2
    )
)
```

So far my solution is:

```
foreach($data['messages'] as $key=>$value){
    if(isset($value->mileage)) {
        if (@$mileage_min > 0) $mileage_max = $value->mileage; else $mileage_min = $value->mileage;
    }               
}
echo $mileage = round($mileage_max - $mileage_min,1);
```

...but maybe it is a better and more elegant way to do that.

Comment: Do not use `@`. that's big no-no.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski this was only to avoid additional lines of codes where you need to define empty variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can simply put this as:

- Collect all the mileages.
- Then, it is just maximum - minimum among them.
- For set/unset issue of `mileage`, use null coalescing operator followed by a `-1` if it isn't set and strip them using `array_filter`.

**Snippet:**

```
<?php

$mileages = array_filter(array_map(fn($obj) => $obj->mileage ?? -1, $data['messages']), fn($val) => $val >= 0);

echo max($mileages) - min($mileages);
```

[**Online Demo**](https://onlinephp.io/c/2145b)

Comment: Thank you. However this doesnt work, I am getting an error: "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW) "
Could you pls look to: https://onlinephp.io/c/9e3f5

BTW. The mileage difference not speed

Comment: @Tikky Updated my code. Why are you executing this for PHP 5 version?

Comment: @Tikky Added an online demo for your reference.

Comment: thank you. I am usign PHP 7.2.29 and this gives me an error. Will tru update to 7.4

Comment: On PHP 7.4 works, as expected. Thank you

Comment: @Tikky Glad it worked for you. Good to see you upgraded your PHP version. I would always recommend upgrading the PHP to whatever latest stable version release is available.